# How to filter result based on ID in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make search based on ID using angularjs filter. I am generating some value based on ID of node like based on userId I am finding name, phone no of user from storage JSON object.

But I am not able to find how to filter result if i have just ID and its JSON object.

I have made jsfiddle to get clear idea about my issue http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/5969/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
Search: <input ng-model="searchTableQuery.id">
<table id="searchTextResults" class="table table-bordered">
  <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchTableQuery">
    <td>{{getCurrentValue(friend.id, friends)}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.friends = [{id: 1, name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                         {id: 2, name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                         {id: 3, name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                         {id: 4, name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                         {id: 5, name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                         {id: 6, name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}];
    $scope.getCurrentValue = function (id, availableData) {
        var result = _.where(availableData, { 'id': id });
        if (_.isEmpty(result)) {
            result = [{id:0,value:""}];
        };
        return result[0].name;
    }
}
```

How to make filter on table using ID of node in angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
Search: <input ng-model="searchTableQuery">
<table id="searchTextResults" class="table table-bordered">
  <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:{id:searchTableQuery}">
    <td>{{getCurrentValue(friend.id, friends)}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: filter:{id:searchTableQuery} is not working. Data is not getting display properly: http://jsfiddle.net/PUDCC/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, angular do read your searchTableQuery but cannot identify it as an attribute of your list of friend objects so it can filter it, or to be more clear doesn't now to what attribute of the friend object does he have to couple it.
To resolve the issue, you have to force the recognition of searchTableQuery as an id by doing : `filter:{id:searchTableQuery}`.

Comment: filter:{id:searchTableQuery} is not working. Data is not getting display properly: http://jsfiddle.net/PUDCC/

Comment: I just noticed that you do have {{getCurrentValue(friend.id, friends)}} in your hg-repeat? why not call friend.id directly?
Try doing <td>{{friend.id}}</td> and leaving the filter as filter:searchTableQuery ... I remember working on the exact same situation and had no trouble doing this. Please try it and let us know.

Comment: No, this is not my requirement. I need to fetch data based on id from localstorage object and then that data i need to show on table.